Django random post not showing on base.html
I'm trying to get ads to show on the sidebar of my website (in base.html). However the ad isn't displaying.
The code I'm using is:
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import random

def base(request):
    allSideAds=SideBarAd.objects.all()
    random_sideAd = random.choice(allSideAds) if allSideAds else None
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'random_sideAd': random_sideAd})

models.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class SideBarAd(models.Model):
    AdImage = models.ImageField(help_text='Enter Image Here')
    AdLink = models.URLField()
    MaxAdViews = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    AdViews = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    Approved = models.BooleanField()
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.AdImage

base.html
        {% if random_sideAd %}
            <a href="{{ random_sideAd.AdLink }}">
                <img src="{{ random_sideAd.AdImage.url }}" alt="Ad Image">
            </a>
        {% endif %}

When I load a page, the ad that's in my database isn't shown through base.html.

Your code won't render anything if SideBarAd.objects.all() returns an empty queryset, so most likely that's the issue.

I was able to figure out why this wasn't working. Instead of running this through views.py, I decided to use context_processors.py.
context_processors.py:
import random
from .models import SideBarAd


def sidebar_ad(request):
    sidebar_ads = SideBarAd.objects.filter(Approved=True)

    sidebar_ad_data = random.choice(sidebar_ads) if sidebar_ads else None

    return {'sidebar_ad': sidebar_ad_data}


It might get heavy memory if objects list get too long.
Consider using:


try to print the allSideAds to make sure it exist, if you are sure you have imported the SideBarAd and there is objects, try
allSideAds= list(SideBarAd.objects.all())
random_sideAd = random.choice(allSideAds)

